# asp:Hyperlink returning null in Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have a `asp:Hyperlink` set up in my applications' formview and a label

```
<br />
<b>Posting Site:</b>
<asp:Label ID="AppleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Apple") %>' />
<br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplPostIt" Text="Text" runat="server"/>
```

and in my `Page_Load` event I attempt to find the label and the hyperlink:

```
Label Apple = FormView1.FindControl("Apple") as Label;
HyperLink hplPostIt = FormView1.FindControl("hplPostIt") as HyperLink;
```

Then I try to use an if statement to change the `NavigateURL` property of the hyperlink based on the text of the label and Visual Studio complains that the object reference is not set. Here is my if else condition:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    lblRow.Text = Request.QueryString["num"];
    hplPostIt.Text = "Eat Now";

    if (Fruit.Text == "Fruit")
    {
       hplPostIt.NavigateUrl = 
              "https://www.mysite.com/Fruit/Apples.aspx?Season=" + 
              SeasonLabel.Text + "&Color_Date=" + TypeLabel.Text + 
              "&num=" + SeasonLabel.Text;
    }
    else
    {
       hplPostIt.NavigateUrl = 
              "Fruit/Apples.aspx?Season=" + SeasonLabel.Text + 
              "&Color_Date=" + TypeLabel.Text + "&num=" + SeasonLabel.Text;
    }
}
```

**Edited**
I left out the Postback check

I have also tried using this in a `protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)` with no luck

Comment: please edit your question and **add some more relevant information** such as formView tag, complete Page_load method and so on! In addition your code shown in the question won't compile.. What error/exception did occur in what line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made **lot of assumptions** and added some code to make a working example for you. In case you think I did not get you, please add some more information by *commenting on my answer* of *editing your question*!

**Assumptions**

- Class `Fruit` - representing your dataContainer - simplified it, to store a name
- on `Page_Load` I bound some demo values
- added a *paging functionality* to provide a working example

**Solution**

1. I used a `customMethod(..)` to bind on property `NavigateUrl`
2. added `string.Format(..)` to concat your strings

**Still unclear**

- Where do SeasonLabel and TypeLabel come from?

**Markup**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:FormView ID="fvFruits" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
   OnPageIndexChanging="fvFruits_PageIndexChanging">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblFruit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hplPostIt" Text="yourText" 
             NavigateUrl='<%# customMethod(Eval("Name")) %>' runat="server"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</div>
</form>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // demo purposes to add some data
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        bindDemoData();
}

private void bindDemoData()
{
    List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Apple" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Banana" });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit() { Name = "Orange" });
    fvFruits.DataSource = fruits;
    fvFruits.DataBind();
}

/// <summary>
/// Custom method to check for a given parameter value, which will be given
/// by the dataBinding within markup code.
/// You might even pass more parameter values
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fruit">the name of the fruit</param>
/// <returns>custom link for each given fruitName</returns>
public string customMethod(object fruit)
{
    if (fruit != null)
    {
        string fruitName = fruit.ToString();
        // insert custom binding here!
        string url = "https://www.mysite.com/Fruit/";
        if (fruitName == "Apple")
            url += "Apples.aspx";
        else if (fruitName == "Banana")
            url += "Banana.aspx";
        else if (fruitName == "Orange")
            url += "Orange.aspx";
        /*else
            url += "defaultFruit.aspx";;  // up to you*/

        // can't see where SeasonLabel and TypeLabel are defined??? please add a comment if I did get you wrong
        url += string.Format("?Season={0}&Color_Date={1}&num={2}", SeasonLabel.Text, TypeLabel.Text, SeasonLabel.Text);

        //uncomment this line and comment out the line above to get a working example
        //url += string.Format("?Season={0}&Color_Date={1}&num={2}", "a", "b", "c");

        return url;
    }
    return "https://www.mysite.com/error.aspx"; // probably - but up to you
}
protected void fvFruits_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    fvFruits.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindDemoData();
}

// demo data container
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Result Pic**

[image: result when testing this code]

Comment: I have not tried this solution, however I did resolve my issue yesterday by taking the hyperlink out of the formview, I think the `DataBind` in the pageload may have resolved my issue, with a little elbow grease

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, you may consider upvoting it and/or marking this question as answered, ty in advance!

Answer (score -1):

**First of all**, use `string.Format` to format a url string

```
hplPostIt.NavigateUrl = string.Format("https://www.mysite.com/Fruit/Apples.aspx?Season={0}&Color_Date={1}&num={2}", SeasonLabel.Text, TypeLabel.Text, SeasonLabel.Text);
```

**Second**
You don't need FindControl to access to hplPostIt, if it located directly on Page. See "youpagename.aspx.design.cs" to find control declaration

**Third**
Probably null reference exception thrown by one of text control (SeasonLabel, TypeLabel)

Comment: As explained in the title and in the description the hyperlink is located inside of a `asp:formview`. Also the nulls are comming from the labels but I do not know why they are returning null.The `format.String` seems useful though

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried running it in the formview databound event rather than page load?

Something like:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound" ...>
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Label Apple = FormView1.FindControl("Apple") as Label;
HyperLink hplPostIt = FormView1.FindControl("hplPostIt") as HyperLink; 
// etc.
}
```

As a workaround

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hplPostIt" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# getLink(Eval("Apple")) >' />
```

Then

```
protected string getLink(object obj)
{
string fruit = obj.ToString();
// if else with fruit string.
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the suggestion but I have already listed that in the edited section of my question.